# Why my Apk size is too big even I used shrinkResources?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I am struck by the problem I used all the google guideline to reduce the size of the apk. I also checked out many answers posted on StackOverflow but no one helps me to reduce the size of my apk. I don't know what the problem? I used shrinkResource, adaptations  but these do not short out my issue
my Gradle file is:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }

}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    google()
}

apply plugin: 'io.fabric'


android {
    /*  signingConfigs {
          config {
              keyAlias 'mykey'
              keyPassword 'mykeyPassword'
              storeFile file('D:/Brijesh/Project/All Project Keystore/MySkoda/mykey.jks')
              storePassword 'mykeyPassword'
          }
      }*/
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias 'mykey'
            keyPassword 'mykeyPassword'
            storeFile file('D:/ajit/other/ex/Skoda/mykey.jks')
            storePassword 'mykeyPassword'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.skodaautoindia.myskoda"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 8
        versionName "1.1.0.5"
        multiDexEnabled true
        /*  signingConfig signingConfigs.config*/
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }


        /*  release {
              minifyEnabled false
              signingConfig signingConfigs.config
          }*/
    }
    aaptOptions {
        cruncherEnabled = false
    }
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    productFlavors {
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.2@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile project(':photo-crop-library')
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.11.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:25.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.5'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'cz.msebera.android:httpclient:4.4.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.weiwangcn.betterspinner:library-material:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.5.2'
    compile 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.4.0'

    compile 'com.albinmathew:photo-crop-library:1.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0-beta1'


}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Thank you very much for your time and assistance in this matter.

Comment: Hi, @Champandroid.... you can used multiple libraries. i think facebook sdk size is bigger

Comment: refer this: https://medium.com/@kevalpatel2106/how-you-can-decrease-application-size-by-60-in-only-5-minutes-47eff3e7874e

Answer (score 1):

This can be usedful to you.

1. Use ProGaurd

   ```
   try

   buildTypes {
   release {
       minifyEnabled true
       shrinkResources true
       proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
   }}
   ```

   - shrinkResources true will not include the images from resources which your using in the final apk
2. Remove any debug info you have in the app ( statements such as Log.i()). They can be wrapped in a condition which is only enabled while testing out the application.
3. Use recommended media formats
   Image: PNG or JPG
   Audio: AAC
   Video: H264 AVC
4. Compress images using OptiPNG or PNGCrush
5. Find unused resources using this tool and remove them.
6. Refrain using multiple resources to achieve the same functionality. The resources is not limited to images but can be extended to APIs. Sometimes, using a singular API which provide multiple results is more efficient than using two or three different APIs. Duplicated strings and assets are also a waste of mermory.

Also Refer this link: [GitHub Reduce APK Size](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/wiki/Strategies-to-reduce-Android-APK-size)

Answer (score 0):

An APK file consists of a ZIP archive that contains all the files that comprise your app. These files include Java class files, resource files, and a file containing compiled resources.

please recheck on your assets and res files.
Although you don't need to export your rasterized assets to each density.

[link](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/reduce-apk-size.html)

Comment: did this all there are no unused resources and by res folder is not more that 20 MB

Comment: That is a bit high broo, please work on it. it will reduce the apk size.

Comment: There is another app which uses 23 MB but apk size is 12 MB only

Answer (score 0):

1. Generate dependency tree for your included dependencies in app level `build.gradle` file
2. use `exclude {}` block for each of the **repeating** dependencies

Example:

```
compile ("com.xxx:xxx-commons:1.+") {
    exclude group: 'junit', module: 'junit'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now you can analyse your APK file in Android Studio 3.0+ By going "Build -> Analyse APK..."

There you will see the detailed information about your APK.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.